A confusion about Lemma 16.2 in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds
In Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds, page 137 Lemma 16.2, it states: Step 1. Let $D_{1},D_{2},\cdots$ be a sequence of compact (rectifiable) subsets of (the open set) $A$ whose union is $A$, such that $D_{i}\subset\mathrm{Int}D_{i+1}$ for each $i$. For convenience in notation, let $D_{i}$ denote the empty set for $i\leq0$. Then for each $i$, define $B_{i}=D_{i}-\mathrm{Int}D_{i-1}$. The set $B_{i}$ is bounded, being a subset of $D_{i}$; and it is closed, being the intersection of closed sets $D_{i}$ and $\mathbf{R}^{n}-\mathrm{Int}D_{i-1}$. Thus $B_{i}$ is compact. Also, $B_{i}$ is disjoint from the closed set $D_{i-2}$, since $D_{i-2}\subset\mathrm{Int}D_{i-1}$.
Munkres just uses the fact that $B_{i}$ is disjoint from the closed set $D_{i-2}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{i-2}B_{k}$ to continue his proof. Then for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$, there exists $\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}}>0$, such that $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from the closed set $D_{i-2}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{i-2}B_{k}$...
However, I think we can also get $B_{i}$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$. It seems that for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$, there exists $\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}}>0$, such that $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$. The difficulty arises from the fact that the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$ is a union of countable many closed set $B_{k}$, which may not be closed. So, how can we prove/disprove for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$, there exists $\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}}>0$, such that $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$?
Here is my try. $B_{i}$ is disjoint from the closed set $B_{i+2}$. Choose any $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$. There exists $\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}}>0$, such that $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from the closed set $B_{i+2}$. We just need to prove if $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from $B_{j} (j\geq i+2)$, then $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from $B_{j+1}$, but how to prove/disprove it?


the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$ is a union of countable many closed set $B_{k}$, which may not be closed.

It is certainly not compact, but closed in $A$. In fact
$$D_{i+2}^{\ast} = A \setminus \operatorname{Int} D_{i+1} .$$
Note that $\operatorname{Int} D_i \subset D_i \subset \operatorname{Int} D_{i+1}$, thus the $\operatorname{Int} D_i$ are an ascending sequence of open sets whose union is $A$.

Let $x \in A \setminus \operatorname{Int} D_{i+1}$. Then $x \notin \operatorname{Int} D_{i+1}$. Since $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{Int} D_{k}$, we have $x \in \operatorname{Int} D_k$ for some $k$. Let $K$ be the minimal index with this property. Clearly $K > i+1$. But then $x \in D_{K} \setminus \operatorname{Int} D_{K-1} = B_K \subset D^*_{i+2}$.

Let $x \in D^*_{i+2}$. Then $x \in B_k$ for some $k \ge i+2$. Thus $x \notin \operatorname{Int} D_{k-1}$ and $x \notin \operatorname{Int} D_{i+1}$ because $\operatorname{Int} D_{i+1} \subset \operatorname{Int} D_{k-1}$.


For $k \ge i+2$ we have $B_i \cap B_k = \emptyset$. To see this, let $x \in B_i$. Since $B_i \subset D_i \subset \operatorname{Int} D_{i+1} \subset \operatorname{Int} D_{k-1}$, we conclude $x \notin D_k \setminus \operatorname{Int} D_{k-1} = B_k$.
Therefore $B_i \cap D^*_{i+2} = \emptyset $ which means that $A \setminus D^*_{i+2}$ is an open neighborhood of $B_i$ in $A$ which is disjoint from $D^*_{i+2}$. Hence each $x \in B_i$ admits $\epsilon_x > 0$ such that $C(x,\epsilon_x) \subset A \setminus D^*_{i+2}$.

I don't understand how your answer solve my key question. How can we prove/disprove for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$, there exists $\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}}>0$, such that $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$?

@studyhard  I thought it  is clear that $B_i \cap D^_{i+2} = \emptyset $ which means that $A \setminus D^{i+2}$ is an open neighborhood of $B_i$ in $A$ which is disjoint from $D^*{i+2}$. I made an update concerning this point.

I just try to answer this question by myself.
First, we need such a lemma: $A$ is an open set in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, $C$ is a compact set in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ and $C\subset A$. Prove there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\bigcup_{\mathbf{x}\in C}B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)\subset\bigcup_{\mathbf{x}\in C}C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)\subset A$.
This lemma is proved in page 34 Theorem 4.6 in Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds.
We know that $\mathrm{Int}D_{i+1}$ is an open set, $D_{i}$ is a compact set, and $D_{i}\subset\mathrm{Int}D_{i+1}$. According to the lemma above, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\bigcup_{\mathbf{x}\in D_{i}}C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)\subset\mathrm{Int}D_{i+1}$; for all $\mathbf{x}\in D_{i}, C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)\subset\mathrm{Int}D_{i+1}$; for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}=D_{i}-\mathrm{Int}D_{i-1}, C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)\subset\mathrm{Int}D_{i+1}$; for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}, C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$.
So, there exists an $\epsilon>0$, for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$, $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$.
So, for all $\mathbf{x}\in B_{i}$, there exists $\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}}>0$, such that $C(\mathbf{x},\epsilon_{\mathbf{x}})$ is disjoint from the set $D_{i+2}^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=i+2}^{\infty}B_{k}$.
Am I right or wrong?
